# convert a vector of string with many chunks to a data frame with a header

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a string vector imported from excel file as a single string `"\r\n\r\nName\r\n\r\nPosition\r\n\r\nAge\r\n\r\nGender\r\n\r\nSam\r\n\r\nManager\r\n\r\n30\r\n\r\n Male\r\n\r\nMira\r\n\r\nHead\r\n\r\n25\r\n\r\nFemale\r\n\r\nMario\r\n\r\n40\r\n\r\nDirector\r\n\r\n Maria\r\n\r\n25\r\n\r\nOfficer\r\n\r\nFemale"`

I am looking to convert this string to a data frame with column names are coming from first four values (Name, Position, Age, Gender). if there any missing cells to be Null or NA.

the table to be

```
Name  | Position | Age | Gender
Sam   | Manager  |  30 | Male
Mira  | Head     |  25 | Female
Mario | Director |  40 | NA
Maria | Officer  |  25 | Officer
```

I split the data into a vector with many rows,

```
bb <- c("\r\n\r\nName\r\n\r\nPosition\r\n\r\nAge\r\n\r\nGender\r\n\r\nSam\r\n\r\nManager\r\n\r\n30\r\n\r\n Male\r\n\r\nMira\r\n\r\nHead\r\n\r\n25\r\n\r\nFemale\r\n\r\nMario\r\n\r\n40\r\n\r\nDirector\r\n\r\n Maria\r\n\r\n25\r\n\r\nOfficer\r\n\r\nFemale")

bb_split <- bb %>% str_split(pattern ="\r\n\r\n") %>% unlist()
```

Then I tried many ways to add a column with a number and try to group rows with this number, but it turned into having a nest list without reaching to my gaol.

I appreciate your support.

Comment: it seems to me that detecting the missing cells is the hard part here... if there were some value (or at least just a double break) where the missing value should be this should be pretty straightforward but as it is it seems nontrivial to properly insert the missing values

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to convert it to a matrix but it became another mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be curious how you did import from Excel, maybe you might be able to use a better method.

However, in your string, after Mario and Maria the order Name, Position, Age, Gender suddenly switches which I assume to be an error. Therefore I use an accordingly re-ordered vector.

The code below uses a regex that splits at the `"\r\n\r\n"` as well as at spaces which are not followed by `"Male"` or `"Female"`.

Of course you need to adapt this logic to the other variables as well, but this might give you an idea of how to solve your problem.

```
b1 <- trimws(el(strsplit(bc, "\r\n\r\n|\\s(?!Male|Female)", perl=TRUE))[-1])
m <- matrix(replace(b1, b1 == "", NA), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
res <- setNames(as.data.frame(m[-1, ]), m[1, ])
res
#    Name Position Age Gender
# 1   Sam  Manager  30   Male
# 2  Mira     Head  25 Female
# 3 Mario Director  40   <NA>
# 4 Maria  Officer  25 Female
```

---

*Data:*

```
bc <- "\r\n\r\nName\r\n\r\nPosition\r\n\r\nAge\r\n\r\nGender\r\n\r\nSam\r\n\r\nManager\r\n\r\n30\r\n\r\n Male\r\n\r\nMira\r\n\r\nHead\r\n\r\n25\r\n\r\nFemale\r\n\r\nMario\r\n\r\nDirector\r\n\r\n40\r\n\r\n Maria\r\n\r\nOfficer\r\n\r\n25\r\n\r\nFemale"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I received the data through Outlook as a HTML table, I tried to use RDCOMClient package to get the data from outlook to R but it though an error. and I couldn't solve that error. so I decided to use Power Automate to download specific email to Excel on OneDrive. so I can extract the data, which now in that format. I don't know if there any better and simple way to get the data from Outlook directly to R.